# Recursive Blum Blum Shub

Tags: random, erlang

Since my [last tattoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186724/why-is-whitespace-sometimes-needed-around-metacharacters) resulted in a syntax error I was thinking of getting it peer reviewed this time around, are there any errors or quirks with this recursive [Blum Blum Shub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) implementation that I have made?

```
f(_, _, 0) -> [];
f(M, S, N) -> R=S*S rem M, [R|f(M, R, N-1)].

% M - The modulo number 
% S - The seed
% N - The number of pseudo random numbers to generate
```

Some simple tests:

```
zero_test() -> [] = f(5, 9, 0).
some_test() -> [9,81,82,36,42] = f(11*19, 3, 5).
static_test() -> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] = f(1,1,10).
```

Comment: for me the code in two lines is too small for review. But in any case better provide full module with test function.

Comment: Added some simple tests